# How chrome URLS work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I say,

```
chrome://downloads
```

here my understanding is, `chrome` is a protocol talking to chrome engine and downloads is like a tag name for specific request to chrome engine.

Is that correct?
How does it work(under the hood)?

Comment: yep. Look at chromes source code...? theres sth like *if(url.protocol==="chrome") dointernalstuff();* However why do you want to know that?

Comment: @Jonasw For writing your own url based functionality.

Comment: so you want to write your own browser? Have fun ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's just an internal protocol handler. Browser itself registers a handler to handle URLs that use that protocol. Browsers even let you register your own protocol handlers nowadays.

For more info see:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler